# Is it possible to get network interface ID of an EC2 using instance metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I get the network interface ID by using [`instance metadata`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) inside an EC2?

I mean I want to get something like `eni-0032fc98a9f0a13bk` for the current EC2 that I'm in.

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces` doesn't work.

The following script works, but it requires [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the response from `aws ec2` command.

```
$ export mac=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac)
$ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces \
  --region my-region \
  --filters Name=mac-address,Values=${mac}
```

I don't want to install extra tools to get the network interface ID.

My EC2 has only one network interface attached to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [--query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter) and [--output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-format):

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region <my-region>  --filters Name=mac-address,Values=${mac} --query "NetworkInterfaces[0].NetworkInterfaceId" --output text
```

Example outcome:

```
eni-04b594570017a3b53
```

The above assumes that you have only one ENI on your instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/"$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs)"interface-id
```

Example outcome:

```
eni-04b594570017a3b53
```

The above assumes that you have only one ENI on your instance.

$() is called command substitution in bash. "" <-- quotes are always good to use even when you don't need them; because when you forget them when you need them you are left scratching your head.

Here is a answer on the topic --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash

So the `$(curl ...)` runs a curl, puts the result in an un-named variable and passes it to the outer curl, and the outer curl gives you the response you want.

Thank you Marcin for providing a template for my answer!

Comment: Hey TelamonAegisthus, I made a fun command you might like to use:
sudo ip address add 172.31.47.247/20 brd + dev eth0 ; aws ec2 assign-private-ip-addresses --network-interface-id "$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/"$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs)"interface-id)" --private-ip-addresses 172.31.47.247